# Reenable Google Chrome updates on Mac

Tags: google-chrome, permissions, sudo

i was wondering if any of you guys is able to help me reenable Google Chrome updates ? Please note that i have no programming knowledge of any kind and i am a total noob.

A friend of mine ran the following line in terminal to stop Chrome from updating.

cd /Library/Google/;sudo chown nobody:nogroup GoogleSoftwareUpdate;sudo chmod 18000 GoogleSoftwareUpdate;cd ~/Library/Google/;sudo chown nobody:nogroup GoogleSoftwareUpdate;sudo chmod 18000 GoogleSoftwareUpdate

But know i a dont know how to reverse that and neither does he. Even when i uninstall Chrome it isnt working. it always says error 10.

Any help would be very much appriciated.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

### When i do a simple Google search i get to this answer:

- Launch the Terminal, found in /Applications/Utilities/ and enter the following defaults write command:

  defaults write com.google.Keystone.Agent checkInterval 18000
- Exit Terminal and restart Google Chrome to reactive automatic updates

The number on the end is the number of seconds between version checking intervals, 18000 is the default setting but if you want to be more or less aggressive select a higher or lower number accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and i did that as well but that does not work unfortunately.

This method works when you disabled it with:

defaults write com.google.Keystone.Agent checkInterval 0

But i used this and this seems to be harder to disable:

cd /Library/Google/;sudo chown nobody:nogroup GoogleSoftwareUpdate;sudo chmod 18000 GoogleSoftwareUpdate;cd ~/Library/Google/;sudo chown nobody:nogroup GoogleSoftwareUpdate;sudo chmod 18000 GoogleSoftwareUpdate

Comment: That command seems to have changed the rights to the folder. Have you tried simply deleting the folder "Google" and "GoogleSoftwareUpdate"?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer and i did taht as well but that does not work unfortenately.

This method works when you disabled it with:

defaults write com.google.Keystone.Agent checkInterval 0

But i used this and this seems to be harder to disable:

cd /Library/Google/;sudo chown nobody:nogroup GoogleSoftwareUpdate;sudo chmod 18000 GoogleSoftwareUpdate;cd ~/Library/Google/;sudo chown nobody:nogroup GoogleSoftwareUpdate;sudo chmod 18000 GoogleSoftwareUpdate